# Delete mailbox based on postfix / dovecot / sql

Tags: sql, perl, postfix-mta, dovecot

I'm writing some PERL code to add/remove mailboxes and aliases on a remote server running a postfix / dovecot / mysql stack.

I'm wondering does anyone have experience or definitive information on what needs to be programatically done on the remote mail server?

For **adding mailboxes**, I believe it's as simple as doing an INSERT of a new row into the *postfix -> mailbox* table. As mail receives/sends, postfix and dovecot will create the relevant file/folders under */var/vmail*.

For **deleting mailboxes**, I believe in addition to a DELETE of the relevant *postfix -> mailbox* table row, I'll also need to run a bash command:

```
rm -rf /var/vmail/[domain]/[username]
```

... in order to clear actual messages and attachments of the user.

I don't think there is anything to do on the Dovecot side, as it uses data in the above mentioned.

P.S. For those interested, I'm using a LWP:UserAgent to send web API over to a local PERL script on the mail server in order to run the DBI and bash commands.

Comment: If you're managing the mailboxes in a database, then I think you've got it covered with the db INSERT or DELETE + folder rm.  You may want to add some logic to delete `/var/vmail/[domain]` once there are no more mailboxes for that domain.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The parent domain folder I think I need to leave alone, since there is a separate SQL table "domain" that contains domain names and later adding a new user might cause errors due to the missing folder. Was hoping somebody on this planet had dealt with this before... but eventually I'll do some testing and see if anything breaks before writing the code.

Comment: Quick update on this: after examining how postfixadmin PHP code deletes mailboxes, it appears it only deletes relevant SQL tables: the actual folders where mail data is stored still remains. The problem is that postfix creates folders and mail as its own user/group (e.g. vmail/vmail) and also writes permissions as 0600 rwx------... so even adding user apache to the group won't let it delete mailboxes "fully". Now investigating how to get postfix to at least write its folders and files with permissions 0770 and 0660 respectively.

Comment: I've noticed the same thing with postfixadmin.  It's a bit annoying that it doesn't or can't fully clean up after itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've solved this challenge.

Firstly, the architecture is a remote mail server running Postfix/Dovecot/MySQL. My management server is its own LAMP stack and within it I have a custom database and table that tracks mailboxes: users, domains, status (amongst other things). I mention this because it will help people formulate their own custom solutions.

However, theoretically it could all run on the same server (just go straight to step 2).

To delete a mailbox this is what I do:

1. From my local server, I use LWP::UserAgent and HTTP::Reqeuest::Common PERL modules to send a GET request to the remote Postfix server. For example, https://remote.com/api.cgi?action=delete&mailbox=john@smith.com.
2. On the remote Postfix server, I also have PERL and Apache installed. As the GET request hits the server, my Apache run PERL script updates the local MySQL *postfix* database *mailbox* table sending this SQL commands:

   ```
   use postfix
   UPDATE mailbox SET status=1,created='1111-11-11 11:11:11'
   ```

   This means that effectively the account is already inactive.

The reason I set the created date to that unique value is because it's a column that won't be changed by normal Postfix operation.

3. On this remote server I have another PERL script that runs as a **daily cron job** with **root** permission. The script first performs a:

   ```
   SELECT local_part,domain FROM mailbox WHERE created='1111-11-11 11:11:11'
   ```
4. I now use the "1111-11-11 11:11:11" to determine which mailboxes to delete. With the resulting array from DBI, the Perl script (with it's **root** privileges then does the following PERL code:

   ```
   for $x (0 .. $#$delete_mailboxes) {
    $check = "/var/vmail/$delete_mailboxes->[$x][1]/$delete_mailboxes->[$x][0]";
    if (-e $check) { @a=system("rm -rf $check") }
   }
   ```

and finishes up with a SQL command:

```
    DELETE FROM mailbox WHERE local_part='$delete_mailboxes->[$x][0]' AND domain='$delete_mailboxes->[$x][1]'
```

Effectively, it's using data already in the *postfix* *mailbox* table to test for which mailboxes to delete, whether the mailbox has existing folder/files to be deleted, and if found, deletes it using root privilege (which overcomes the tight file system permissions.

Now this technique can be done in multiple different programming languages, using different versions of postfix, different database versions and different web service APIs... the important point is that it uses root privilege in a cron job to query the database to determine if/what to delete.

Hopefully this will help save someone a lot of time.